Changing PAR (pixel aspect ratio) in mov file
I accidentally recorded the file in VirtualDub in avi format instead of mov (ProRes).
How to copy it to a mov file (it's easy using ffmpeg with -c copy), but at the same time change PAR to 12/11 (I can do this for mp4, but it doesn't work here).
